# I am trying to integrate log4j2 with my web application. How do I set the path of the log file to one directory level up?

Tags: unix, openshift, log4j2

I am using the following configuration for the **log4j2.properties** file:

```
appender.logfile.fileName=../logs/test.log
```

However instead of going one directory up, and creating the **test.log** file in a folder called logs, it is creating the logs folder in its current location.

I am running my web application on Jboss using openshift.

Please help me out.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Have you tried adding foldername without `../`

Comment: Can you show your full configuration? This snippet looks like a log4j-1.x config, not log4j2...

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your help. Its working now..Basically we moved to using a log4j2.xml configuration file and also in the trace logs we noticed that since the filePattern attribute was not given it wasn't loading the appender properly. Thanks.